# Text editor in c++?

Tags: c++

I was going to do something with PHP, but it was quite a hassle and didn't need to be on a website, so I've decided to try it in c++. I've had some experience with javascript, so I'm not completely new to programming, although I know c++ is definitely quite a bit tougher. I figure I'll start with something basic and work my way up from there.

So, for now, I'd like to make a cross-platform text-editor in c++ using something like MS Visual Studio. Are there any tutorials for something like this?

I'm sure there a ton of this kind of thing, so if you know of any simple source codes, please let me know so I can try to make sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/index.html), it's a fantastic cross-platform text-editing component used in a lot of software.

I don't like discouraging people, but... if you only have Javascript experience, moving over to C++ is going to be a pretty big undertaking even without a GUI project.  Start smaller and work your way up.

Comment: What should I start with then?

Comment: I think most people start out in console for a while.  After you're comfortable, try finding an Open Source project to contribute to.

Answer (score 1):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) for sure. You can get vim on almost all platforms, and it is default editors for many *nix distributions. It has great power and relatively easy to learn (compared to Emacs). Usually once you've learnt vim, you would never need to learn another editor again.